# Provide the user to input multiple values at once in Scilab

Tags: user-input, scilab

I want the user to input the coordinates of 4 points such as (xa,ya),(xb,yb),(xc,yc),(xd,yd) but all of it at once. I used this code:

> xa=input("Enter x-coordinate for node 1:")
>
> ya=input("Enter y-coordinate for node 1:")
>
> xb=input("Enter x-coordinate for node 2:")
>
> yb=input("Enter y-coordinate for node 2:")
>
> xc=input("Enter x-coordinate for node 3:")
>
> yc=input("Enter y-coordinate for node 3:")
>
> xd=input("Enter x-coordinate for node 4:")
>
> yd=input("Enter y-coordinate for node 4:")

but in this case I am able to give input value for yd only.
How can I make the user input all the values at once?

Answer (score 0):

You can take the input as a string and parse it using `strsplit` and `evstr`. Here is a simple example, taking some numbers and returning their sum.

```
str = input("Enter a space-separated list of numbers: ", "string")
v = evstr(strsplit(str, " "))
disp(sum(v), "The sum:")
```

In your case, the input may contain parentheses, commas and spaces, so it's split by a regular expression: `/[ ,;()]+/` meaning any sequence of spaces, parentheses, commas and semicolons (just in case). The user might make a mistake entering data, so a basic check is implemented: the result should have 8 numbers.

```
need_input = %t
while need_input
  str = input("Enter four pairs of coordinates: ", "string")
  v = evstr(strsplit(str, "/[ ,;()]+/"))
  need_input = (length(v) <> 8)
end
coords = matrix(v, 2, 4)
```

Entering `(2,4), (-3, 4), (-9,5), (0, 1)` will result in `coords` matrix being

```
2.  - 3.  - 9.    0.  
4.    4.    5.    1.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the mscanf function
mprintf("Enter four pairs of coordinates: \n")
coords=mscanf("%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f")
User must enter 8 values separated by space

or simply with input
str = input("Enter four pairs of coordinates: ", "string")
coords=evstr("["+str+"]")
User must enter 8 values separated by space